# How Object-name.writeBoolean(boolean value) is not showing console output?

Tags: java, io

I am learning I/O in Java, in `InputStream` and `OutputStream` classes subclass `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` objects behave differently with the data types when Console I/O such that it does not print boolean values.

```
DataInputStream ObjIn = new DataInputStream(System.in);
bool = ObjIn.readBoolean();
```

`bool` is a variable of boolean type.

```
DataOutputStream ObjOu = new DataOutputStream(System.out);
ObjOu.writeBoolean(bool);
```

Anyone please explain the concept behind it. Why the boolean is not print on console I/O.

Comment: What do you mean by "he boolean is not print on console I/O"? What output did you actually get? And what did you expect to get?

Comment: i am getting nothing , and the answer i excepted which i had assign to bool , like either true or false.

Answer (score 3):

`DataOutputStream` writes *binary*, not human readable *text*. Assuming that you `flush`ed the stream, [`writeBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBoolean(boolean)) writes either a 0x00 byte or a 0x01 byte to the stream, depending on the boolean, not the characters "true" or "false".

> Writes a boolean to the underlying output stream as a 1-byte value. The value `true` is written out as the value `(byte)1`; the value `false` is written out as the value `(byte)0`.

*When interpreted as text*, the byte 0x00 and 0x01 are control characters in all the encodings I know, and your console may not display them. This could be why you see no output. Another reason why you see no output is because you did not `flush` your stream.

Similarly, [`DataInput.readBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInput.html#readBoolean()) also reads binary.It reads all non-zero bytes as true, and zero as false, which might have created the illusion of "it is able to read text", when in fact, it is only reading the first byte.

While you can convert the `boolean` to a `String`, and then use `DataOutputStream.writeChars`, I'd suggest just use `System.out` directly. `System.out` is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html), which does all the conversions to `String` for you.

```
System.out.println(bool);
```

Otherwise, the [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) and [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) classes can be used to read text from and write text to arbitrary I/O streams.